# Fast way to find if IPv6 belongs to network range

Tags: c#

I've created a simple script to detect if an IP is in a fixed number of networks (if IP is part of CIDR IP range). Unfortunately the performance goal was not met. 50 checks(`for loop`) if an IPv6 belongs to one one of 250 networks takes 55ms, which is way slower than what is expected. I supply a short version of the program and code in hope of finding a more performant solution. I used https://github.com/lduchosal/ipnetwork library because I didn't know how to perform bitwise shifts on 128 bits of data needed to store IPv6.

I don't include a large block of IPv4s, because IPv4 lookups are 3x faster. IPv6 were duplicated a few times to simulate large block.
Thats how you call it:

```
 using System;
 using System.Globalization;
 using System.Net;

 namespace CIDR_lookup
 {
  internal class Program

  {
    public static void Main(string[] args){

      // initilizes static cache by triggering a call to static constructor. i and jk arrays are not used
      IPNetwork[] i = CidrLookup.subnetCache;
      IPNetwork[] jk = CidrLookup.subnetCache6;
      Console.WriteLine(jk.Length);


      var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
      bool IsIn = false;
      for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++){
        IsIn= CidrLookup.IpInRange(IPAddress.Parse("2a03:2880::1").GetAddressBytes());
      }

      watch.Stop();
      var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
      Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: "+ elapsedMs);
   }
 }
}
```

This is the class code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Numerics;

namespace CIDR_lookup
{
  public partial class CidrLookup
  {
    public static IPNetwork[] subnetCache;
    public static IPNetwork[] subnetCache6;

    static CidrLookup(){
      subnetCache = CidrLookup.CreateSubnets(_ipRanges);
      subnetCache6 = CidrLookup.CreateSubnets(_ipRanges6);
    }



    public static bool IpInRange(byte[] ipBytes){

      IPAddress ip = new IPAddress(ipBytes);

        if (ip.AddressFamily  == AddressFamily.InterNetwork){
          foreach (var subnet in subnetCache){
            bool isIn = subnet.Contains(ip);
            if (isIn){
              return true;
            }
          }
        }
        else{
          foreach (var subnet in subnetCache6){
            bool isIn = subnet.Contains(ip);
            if (isIn){
              return true;
            }
          }
        }

      return false;
    }

    public static IPNetwork[] CreateSubnets(string ipRanges){
      string[] ipRangesArray = ipRanges.Split('\n');
      IPNetwork[] table = new IPNetwork[ipRangesArray.Length];

      for (int i = 0; i < ipRangesArray.Length; i++){
        table[i] = IPNetwork.Parse(ipRangesArray[i]);
      }

      return table;
    }

    public static string IpRanges
    {
      get { return _ipRanges; }
      set { _ipRanges = value; }
    }

    public static string IpRanges6
    {
      get { return _ipRanges6; }
      set { _ipRanges6 = value; }
    }


    private static string _ipRanges6 = @"2604:ca00:f001::/48
    2604:ca00:f004::/48
    2402:9800:8001:0:0:0:0:0/48
    2604:ca00:f009::/48
    2604:ca00:9::/48
    2604:ca00:f008::/48
    2604:ca00:8::/48
    2604:ca00:1a0::/43
    2604:ca00:f::/48
    2604:ca00:d000::/48
    2604:ca00:f000::/48
    2605:ef80:240::/42
    2605:ef80:300::/40
    2605:ef80:400::/42
    2605:ef80:600::/40
    2605:ef80:900::/40
    2607:f8b0:4000::/48
    2a00:79e1:abc::/46
    2a03:ace0:100::/40
    2a03:ace0:200::/40
    2a03:ace0:300::/40
    2605:ef80::/32
    2a03:ace0::/32
    2605:ef80::/42
    2605:ef80:100::/42
    2605:ef80:140::/42
    2605:ef80:180::/42
    2605:ef80:1c0::/42
    2605:ef80:40::/42
    2605:ef80:80::/42
    2605:ef80:c0::/42
    2605:59C0::/32
    2604:ca00::/32
    2604:ca00:f001::/48
    2604:ca00:f004::/48
    2402:9800:8001:0:0:0:0:0/48
    2604:ca00:f009::/48
    2604:ca00:9::/48
    2604:ca00:f008::/48
    2604:ca00:8::/48
    2604:ca00:1a0::/43
    2604:ca00:f::/48
    2604:ca00:d000::/48
    2604:ca00:f000::/48
    2605:ef80:240::/42
    2605:ef80:300::/40
    2605:ef80:400::/42
    2605:ef80:600::/40
    2605:ef80:900::/40
    2607:f8b0:4000::/48
    2a00:79e1:abc::/46
    2a03:ace0:100::/40
    2a03:ace0:200::/40
    2a03:ace0:300::/40
    2605:ef80::/32
    2a03:ace0::/32
    2605:ef80::/42
    2605:ef80:100::/42
    2605:ef80:140::/42
    2605:ef80:180::/42
    2605:ef80:1c0::/42
    2605:ef80:40::/42
    2605:ef80:80::/42
    2605:ef80:c0::/42
    2605:59C0::/32
    2604:ca00::/32
    2604:ca00:f001::/48
    2604:ca00:f004::/48
    2402:9800:8001:0:0:0:0:0/48
    2604:ca00:f009::/48
    2604:ca00:9::/48
    2604:ca00:f008::/48
    2604:ca00:8::/48
    2604:ca00:1a0::/43
    2604:ca00:f::/48
    2604:ca00:d000::/48
    2604:ca00:f000::/48
    2605:ef80:240::/42
    2605:ef80:300::/40
    2605:ef80:400::/42
    2605:ef80:600::/40
    2605:ef80:900::/40
    2607:f8b0:4000::/48
    2a00:79e1:abc::/46
    2a03:ace0:100::/40
    2a03:ace0:200::/40
    2a03:ace0:300::/40
    2605:ef80::/32
    2a03:ace0::/32
    2605:ef80::/42
    2605:ef80:100::/42
    2605:ef80:140::/42
    2605:ef80:180::/42
    2605:ef80:1c0::/42
    2605:ef80:40::/42
    2605:ef80:80::/42
    2605:ef80:c0::/42
    2605:59C0::/32
    2604:ca00::/32
    2604:ca00:f001::/48
    2604:ca00:f004::/48
    2402:9800:8001:0:0:0:0:0/48
    2604:ca00:f009::/48
    2604:ca00:9::/48
    2604:ca00:f008::/48
    2604:ca00:8::/48
    2604:ca00:1a0::/43
    2604:ca00:f::/48
    2604:ca00:d000::/48
    2604:ca00:f000::/48
    2605:ef80:240::/42
    2605:ef80:300::/40
    2605:ef80:400::/42
    2605:ef80:600::/40
    2605:ef80:900::/40
    2607:f8b0:4000::/48
    2a00:79e1:abc::/46
    2a03:ace0:100::/40
    2a03:ace0:200::/40
    2a03:ace0:300::/40
    2605:ef80::/32
    2a03:ace0::/32
    2605:ef80::/42
    2605:ef80:100::/42
    2605:ef80:140::/42
    2605:ef80:180::/42
    2605:ef80:1c0::/42
    2605:ef80:40::/42
    2605:ef80:80::/42
    2605:ef80:c0::/42
    2605:59C0::/32
    2604:ca00::/32
    2604:ca00:f001::/48
    2604:ca00:f004::/48
    2402:9800:8001:0:0:0:0:0/48
    2604:ca00:f009::/48
    2604:ca00:9::/48
    2604:ca00:f008::/48
    2604:ca00:8::/48
    2604:ca00:1a0::/43
    2604:ca00:f::/48
    2604:ca00:d000::/48
    2604:ca00:f000::/48
    2605:ef80:240::/42
    2605:ef80:300::/40
    2605:ef80:400::/42
    2605:ef80:600::/40
    2605:ef80:900::/40
    2607:f8b0:4000::/48
    2a00:79e1:abc::/46
    2a03:ace0:100::/40
    2a03:ace0:200::/40
    2a03:ace0:300::/40
    2605:ef80::/32
    2a03:ace0::/32
    2605:ef80::/42
    2605:ef80:100::/42
    2605:ef80:140::/42
    2605:ef80:180::/42
    2605:ef80:1c0::/42
    2605:ef80:40::/42
    2605:ef80:80::/42
    2605:ef80:c0::/42
    2605:59C0::/32
    2604:ca00::/32
    2604:ca00:f001::/48
    2604:ca00:f004::/48
    2402:9800:8001:0:0:0:0:0/48
    2604:ca00:f009::/48
    2604:ca00:9::/48
    2604:ca00:f008::/48
    2604:ca00:8::/48
    2604:ca00:1a0::/43
    2604:ca00:f::/48
    2604:ca00:d000::/48
    2604:ca00:f000::/48
    2605:ef80:240::/42
    2605:ef80:300::/40
    2605:ef80:400::/42
    2605:ef80:600::/40
    2605:ef80:900::/40
    2607:f8b0:4000::/48
    2a00:79e1:abc::/46
    2a03:ace0:100::/40
    2a03:ace0:200::/40
    2a03:ace0:300::/40
    2605:ef80::/32
    2a03:ace0::/32
    2605:ef80::/42
    2605:ef80:100::/42
    2605:ef80:140::/42
    2605:ef80:180::/42
    2605:ef80:1c0::/42
    2605:ef80:40::/42
    2605:ef80:80::/42
    2605:ef80:c0::/42
    2605:59C0::/32
    2604:ca00::/32
    2604:ca00:f001::/48
    2604:ca00:f004::/48
    2402:9800:8001:0:0:0:0:0/48
    2604:ca00:f009::/48
    2604:ca00:9::/48
    2604:ca00:f008::/48
    2604:ca00:8::/48
    2604:ca00:1a0::/43
    2604:ca00:f::/48
    2604:ca00:d000::/48
    2604:ca00:f000::/48
    2605:ef80:240::/42
    2605:ef80:300::/40
    2605:ef80:400::/42
    2605:ef80:600::/40
    2605:ef80:900::/40
    2607:f8b0:4000::/48
    2a00:79e1:abc::/46
    2a03:ace0:100::/40
    2a03:ace0:200::/40
    2a03:ace0:300::/40
    2605:ef80::/32
    2a03:ace0::/32
    2605:ef80::/42
    2605:ef80:100::/42
    2605:ef80:140::/42
    2605:ef80:180::/42
    2605:ef80:1c0::/42
    2605:ef80:40::/42
    2605:ef80:80::/42
    2605:ef80:c0::/42
    2605:59C0::/32";

    private static string _ipRanges = @"1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subnetting in IPv6 is typically no smaller than a /64. You can use two longs as network and mask respectively to check. If you do want to permit longer subnets, you could use a 128-bit integer library or use two sets of longs for the high and low bits.